# The correctness of standardisation of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

$X$ is a random variable and $Y$ has an equation given below:
$$Y=\frac{X-\mathbb{E}(X)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)}}$$
How to prove that $\mathbb{E}(Y)=0$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y)=1$?

Comment: Can you list properties of expectation and variance you know and could use? Say, things like $\mathbb{E}[aX+b] =...$ and $\mathrm{Var}[aX+b] =...$? (For $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's write this a little differently:
$$Y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{Var(X)}}}X - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{Var(X)}}}\mathbb{E}(X)$$
Remember here that the variance and expected value of $X$ are just numbers. Nothing more. This means that we can use that linearity of the expected value: $\mathbb{E}[aX+b] = \mathbb{E}(aX)+\mathbb{E}(b) = a\mathbb{E}(X)+b$ to find
$$\begin{align}\mathbb{E}(Y) &= \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{Var(X)}}}X\right) - \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{Var(X)}}}\mathbb{E}(X)\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{Var(X)}}}\mathbb{E}(X) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{Var(X)}}}\mathbb{E}(X) = 0\end{align}$$

Similarly, you can do the very same thing to show that $\text{Var}(Y) = 1$. However, it has some slightly different properties. Can you do that one yourself?

Comment: Of course. Thank you!